# Не работает скрипт, который должен преобразовывать изображение используя PowerShell и FFMPEG

Tags: windows, powershell

Смысл в чем, есть скрипт на **PowerShell**, он должен находить **изображения**, преобразовывать с помощью **FFMPEG**, удалять старые, а потом упаковывать в архив, желательно в **.tar**, но проблема в том, что он не работает и я не могу понять почему, он просто отказывается работать.

```
$tarPath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

try {
    # Создание временной папки
    $tempFolder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (Join-Path $pwd "tmp")
# Обработка файлов и конвертация их в формат webP
$fileTypes = "*.jpg", "*.png", "*.jpeg"
Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\Test" -Filter ($fileTypes -join ',') -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $outputFile = Join-Path $tempFolder.FullName "$($_.BaseName).webP"
    ffmpeg -y -i $_.FullName -vf "scale=w=-2:h=-2" $outputFile
    if(Test-Path $outputFile) {
        & $tarPath a -ms -mhe -si "E:\Test\example.tar" $outputFile
        Write-Host "Добавлен файл $outputFile в архив"
        Remove-Item $outputFile
    }
}

# Добавление файлов в архив и удаление исходных файлов
$excludePath = @($tempFolder.FullName)
$excludePath += "E:\Test\*.jpg", "E:\Test\*.png", "E:\Test\*.jpeg"
& $tarPath a -ms -mhe -si "E:\Test\example.tar" -x@($excludePath) -r
Write-Host "Добавлены все файлы в архив"

# Удаление временной папки
Remove-Item $tempFolder -Recurse -Force
Write-Host "Удалена временная папка"

# Удаление скрипта
Remove-Item $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
Write-Host "Удален скрипт"

} catch {
    Write-Host "Произошла ошибка: $_"
    Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
}
```